# Redirecting with a error message not working in Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

please check the below code i have done research but not working
and check all kind of messages like flash or direct message with() and all but not working some help must be approciate.
thank you in advanced

```
 public function paymentfailed(Request $request){

    $request->session()->flash('error', 'Payment failed!');
    return redirect()->route('home')->with('error','Payment Failed.');
 }
```

and my view file is below

```
@if ($error = Session::get('error'))
<script>
    toastr["error"]("'{{ $error }}'");
</script>
@endif
@if ($error = session('error'))
<script>
    toastr["error"]("'{{ $error }}'");
</script>
@endif
@if (session()->has('error'))
<script>
    toastr["error"]("'{{ session()->get('error') }}'");
</script>
@endif

@if($error or '')
<script>
toastr["error"]("{{ $error }}");
</script>
@endif
@if($errors->any())
<script>
    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        toastr["error"]("{{ $error }}");
    @endforeach
</script>
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

In your controller method :

```
\Session::flash('error', 'This is my error');
```

And in your view :

```
@if (Session::has('error'))
<script>
    toastr["error"]("'{{ Session::get('error }}'");
</script>
@endif
```

Comment: Have you tried to display the error without the script markup ? Maybe it's not a Laravel issue ?

Comment: now its working the issue not in javascript issue in Kernel.php not fething ShareErrorsFromSession so i added and its working now thanks